# Checking if a element exists in a list without using an 'in' operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code which continually asks for user input. Once one of these inputs has been repeated, the while loop breaks and prints a line of the repeated input. 
My code so far looks like this:

```
ls = []
i = 1
while True:
    user = input("Give me an input:")
    ls.append(user)
    if user in ls:
        print("Input number {} is not unique!".format(user))
    i += 1
```

However, when i run the code it doesn't perform the way i'd like it to:

```
[user@sahara ~]$ python3 no_repeats.py
Give me an input:4
Input number 4 is not unique!
[user@sahara ~]$
```

How can i fix this? I'm a beginner so simple explanations please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to move the condition one line up,

```
ls = []
i = 1
while True:
    user = input("Give me an input:")
    if user in ls:
        print("Input number {} is not unique!".format(user))
    ls.append(user)
    i += 1
```

Explanation: basically, you are asking whether the item is already on the list *right after* adding it. So, it will always be on the list :)

Comment: i want to find a way around using an in operator however. is there a way to do that? i cant seem to think of any

Comment: There are a few alternatives, see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-check-if-element-exists-in-list/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `in` is relevant to your issue.

You simply stored the value too soon,
you stored it prior to the test.
Do this:

```
    if user in ls:
        print("Input number {} is not unique!".format(user))
        break
    ls.append(user)
```

Test the history first,
**then** store the value for use by subsequent loops.

You will need that `break` if you ever want the `while True:` loop to end.

Also, so far `i` doesn't seem to be necessary.